# Visual Studio 2019 не видит .NET Framework 4.6.2

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Возникла проблема. Мне нужно писать код с .NET Framework 4.6.2.
Всё установил как надо. И через Visual Studio Installer и с сайта Microsoft, но всё равно ничего не выходит, VS просто не видит 4.6.2, даже остальные .NET Framework's

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы скорее всего при создании выбрали `Class Library`, который предназначен для `.NET Core` и `.NET Standard`. Чтобы создать под `.NET Framework` выберете из списка доступных типов проектов `Class Library (.NET Framework)` и дальше уже у вас появится возможность выбрать .NET Framework 4.6.2.

[image: Создание проекта]

[image: Выбор версии]

Comment: Exploding Kitten - оперативно вы... только хотел сам написать то же самое :-)

Comment: Спасибо большое!